# Activate an Open MS Access File to SendKeys With VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel-2016, ms-access-2016

I am trying to send key strokes to an open Microsoft Acess file so that I can export data to an excel file via the toolbar. How can I activate the open Access file in VBA code so that it is the window of focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate the open Access application using `AppActivate` and the title of the window.

The title of the window, however, depends on what's currently open:

If no database is open:

```
AppActivate GetObject(, "Access.Application").Name 'Or AppActivate "Microsoft Access"
```

If a database is open that doesn't have a custom title:

```
AppActivate GetObject(, "Access.Application").CurrentDb.Name 'Or AppActivate "FileName.accdb"
```

If a database is open that has a custom title:

```
AppActivate GetObject(, "Access.Application").CurrentDb.Properties!AppTitle 'Or AppActivate "The title"
```

Do note that automating Access using SendKeys is *doing it wrong* in my opinion. Access has an object model just like Excel, and you can link the two really easily using COM. It's generally way more reliable than using SendKeys,